# getURLEntities twitter4j

Tags: twitter4j

Im using the getURLEntities() (twitter 4 j)

```
    b.getURLEntities().toString();
```

instead of getting the url entities, i m getting console output which looks something like:

> [Ltwitter4j.URLEntity;@ccd249
>   [Ltwitter4j.URLEntity;@101f287
>   [Ltwitter4j.URLEntity;@d9973a
>   [Ltwitter4j.URLEntity;@1578426
>   [Ltwitter4j.URLEntity;@a4effe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the [documentation](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/URLEntity.html) again.

The `getURLEntities()` method returns an array of `URLEntity`

```
URLEntity[] urls = b.getURLEntities();
```

If you want to output this properly the best thing to do it use a loop

```
for(URLEntity url : urls){
  System.out.println(url.getURL());
}
```